# Wait for side effect finish before emit

Tags: rx-java, rx-android

I obtain list of music files from database

```
public Flowable<List<MusicFile>> getMusicFiles() {
    return database.musicDao().getMusicFiles();
}
```

Also, I have a method that downloads a single file from storage (implementation doesn't matter actually):

```
public Completable downloadFile(MusicFile musicFile) {
    String fileKey = musicFile.getFileName();
    File toFile = new File(context.getExternalFilesDir(null).getAbsolutePath() + "/" + fileKey);
    return Completable.create(e -> transferUtility.download(AWS_S3_BUCKET, fileKey, toFile)
            .setTransferListener(new TransferListener() {
                @Override
                public void onStateChanged(int id, TransferState state) {
                    if (TransferState.COMPLETED.equals(state)) {
                        e.onComplete();
                    }
                }
                //...
              );
}
```

I have one solution, but it looks really ugly

```
private List<MusicFile> cache;
@Override
public Flowable<List<MusicFile>> getMusicFiles() {
    return database.musicDao().getMusicFiles()
    .flatMapCompletable(new Function<List<MusicFile>, CompletableSource>() {
        @Override
        public CompletableSource apply(List<MusicFile> musicFiles) throws Exception {
            cache = musicFiles;
            int tracksAmount = musicFiles.size();
            List<Completable> downloadTasks = new ArrayList<Completable>(tracksAmount);
            for (int i = 0; i < tracksAmount; i++) {
                downloadTasks.add(aws.downloadFile(musicFiles.get(i)));
            }
            return Completable.merge(downloadTasks);
        }
    }).toFlowable().flatMap(o -> Flowable.just(cache));
}
```

Is is possible to avoid caching files and just to wait somehow for every file is loaded?

Comment: Can you make the `downloadFile()` method into `Observable<MusicFile>`? That way you can do a straightforward, nested observable chain, using `flatMap( fileList -> Flowable.from(fileList).map(file -> downloadFile(file)).toList())`.

Comment: Makes sense. I'll try and let you know. Thanks.